# Can the data at UseMachineKeyStore be backed up and recovered?

Tags: rsacryptoserviceprovider

I have the following code:

```
const int PROVIDER_RSA_FULL = 1;
const string CONTAINER_NAME = "Example";
CspParameters cspParams;
cspParams = new CspParameters(PROVIDER_RSA_FULL);
cspParams.KeyContainerName = CONTAINER_NAME;
cspParams.Flags = CspProviderFlags.UseMachineKeyStore;
cspParams.ProviderName = "Microsoft Strong Cryptographic Provider";
RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cspParams);
```

As I understand it, a keypair is generated automatically and then becomes the referenced key pair using the KeyContainerName "Example".

I'm using a dedicated host. I want to be sure that our hosting company are aware of this information being important, making sure it's backed up, and not losing it, because then all the information I have encrypted and stored in a database will be useless.

I can't find any word in MSDN about how it works in the background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The Key containers are stored in the
>   file system. The directories are
>   Machine Keys: documents and
>   settings\all
>   users\application\data\microsoft\crypto
>   and subdirectories.
>
> Be aware that you can not "reuse"
>   those keys on other machines or if you
>   are going to rebuild your machine!

[Ref.](http://www.secnewsgroups.net/group/microsoft.public.dotnet.security/topic6886.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, helpful answer, but do you have a source?